# BPM formula should be explained

Tags: business-process-management

I found a code but I don't really understand the formula for BPM = (1.0 / PulseInterval) * 60.0 * 1000;  60.0 should be 1 minute (beats per minute) but why 1.0/ PulseInterval) and *1000?

```
    int UpperThreshold = 518;
int LowerThreshold = 490;
int reading = 0;
float BPM = 0.0;
bool IgnoreReading = false;
bool FirstPulseDetected = false;
unsigned long FirstPulseTime = 0;
unsigned long SecondPulseTime = 0;
unsigned long PulseInterval = 0;
const unsigned long delayTime = 10;
const unsigned long delayTime2 = 1000;
const unsigned long baudRate = 9600;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis2 = 0;
int Signal;
void bpm() {
    reading = Signal;
    // Heart beat leading edge detected.
    if (reading > UpperThreshold && IgnoreReading == false) {
        if (FirstPulseDetected == false) {
            FirstPulseTime = millis();
            FirstPulseDetected = true;
        } else {
            SecondPulseTime = millis();
            PulseInterval = SecondPulseTime - FirstPulseTime;
            FirstPulseTime = SecondPulseTime;
        }
        IgnoreReading = true;
if (reading < LowerThreshold && IgnoreReading == true) {
        IgnoreReading = false;
        noTone(pinSPEAKER);
        digitalWrite(blinkPin, LOW);
    }
    // Calculate Beats Per Minute.
    BPM = (1.0 / PulseInterval) * 60.0 * 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulse interval is in milliseconds.
Divide by 1000 to get seconds.
You don’t want beats per second, but beats per minute.
There are 60 seconds in a minute.
Divide by 60x1000 to change from millisecond to minute.

Another name for pulse interval is pulse period.

Inverse of period is frequency.

It looks like millis() converts clock value to milliseconds.